# JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager with 2059

Tags: database

JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'RBA.QM.GZ' with connection mode 'Client'
and host name 'rba007.in.ibm.com(1416)'. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode,
check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059'
('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE').

am getting this two errors can any one tell.